# react-native icon falls under View

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Icon falls under View in Android but works in ios. And i tried `overflow: 'visible'` , `elevation: 887879778` and `zIndex: 564654687` but nothing helped.

---

Here is screenshots:

- [in ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYmpT.png)
- [in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlON1.png)

---

[**example snack**](https://snack.expo.io/@mahwd/select-your-side)

Comment: Can you add the current style for the icon and for the view please ?

Comment: What component are you using to display the icon? Any specific component library?

Comment: i put example snack above. I used 'native-base' library for icon
[example snack](https://snack.expo.io/@mahwd/select-your-side)

Comment: Try [this one](https://snack.expo.io/rJD1Vmzfm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This structure works okay.
Put that views inside parent and use with padding.

```
<View style={{ padding: 18 }}>
  <View style={styles.left}>
   <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Left</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.icon}>
   <Icon type="Feather" name="check" />
  </View>
</View>
```

Sure not brilliant solution, but fits for this issue